# Unable to access High Availablity Management for clustering via web in RHEL6 after starting luci service

Tags: rhel6

I am trying to setup clustering in RHEL 6.6. Though the luci service has been started, the High Availability Management web page doesn't load.

For eg :

```
[root@red1 Desktop]# service ricci start
Starting ricci:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@red1 Desktop]# passwd ricci
Changing password for user ricci.
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[root@red1 Desktop]# service luci start
Start luci...                                              [  OK  ]
Point your web browser to https://red1.com:8084 (or equivalent) to access luci
```

I get above URL to open the but browser fails with error message as below:

> An error occurred during a connection to red1.com:8084. Issuer certificate is invalid. (Error code: sec_error_ca_cert_invalid)

Please advise.

Comment: Always Check RHCS logs /var/log/cluster/
These logs will help to analyse if HA services are proper or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to start rgmanager which I guess was the problem.

```
service rgmanager start
```

After running this along with rest of the services things became smooth in the below order.

```
service ricci start
service lucy start
service rgmanager start
service cman start
```